# Using Show with GeologicalPeriodData

Tags: graphics, geographics

In an effort to understand how to use GeologicalPeriodData and extending an example provided in the instructions, I created four GeoGraphics plots of bedrock of varying ages.  Each sizes nicely, as can be seen by the following code:

```
bedrockPaleocene = GeologicalPeriodData["PaleoceneEpoch", "BedrockPolygon"];

paleocene = 
 GeoGraphics[{Line @@@ 
 EntityValue[
  EntityClass["AdministrativeDivision", 
 "ContiguousUSStates"], 
  EntityProperty["AdministrativeDivision", "Polygon"]], 
 GeoStyling[Red], bedrockPaleocene}, 
 GeoCenter -> 
 Entity["City", {"NewOrleans", "Louisiana", 
 "UnitedStates"}], 
  GeoRange -> Quantity[1500, "Miles"], 
 GeoBackground -> "ReliefMap"];

bedrockEocene = 
 GeologicalPeriodData["EoceneEpoch", "BedrockPolygon"];
eocene = GeoGraphics[{Line @@@ 
 EntityValue[
  EntityClass["AdministrativeDivision", 
"ContiguousUSStates"], 
  EntityProperty["AdministrativeDivision", "Polygon"]], 
  GeoStyling[Yellow], bedrockEocene}, 
 GeoCenter -> 
 Entity["City", {"NewOrleans", "Louisiana", 
 "UnitedStates"}], 
 GeoRange -> Quantity[1500, "Miles"], 
 GeoBackground -> "ReliefMap"];

bedrockMiocene = 
 GeologicalPeriodData["MioceneEpoch", "BedrockPolygon"];
miocene = 
 GeoGraphics[{Line @@@ 
 EntityValue[
  EntityClass["AdministrativeDivision", 
 "ContiguousUSStates"], 
  EntityProperty["AdministrativeDivision", "Polygon"]], 
  GeoStyling[Green], bedrockMiocene}, 
 GeoCenter -> 
 Entity["City", {"NewOrleans", "Louisiana", 
"UnitedStates"}], 
 GeoRange -> Quantity[1500, "Miles"], 
 GeoBackground -> "ReliefMap"];

bedrockPliocene = 
 GeologicalPeriodData["PlioceneEpoch", "BedrockPolygon"];
pliocene = 
 GeoGraphics[{Line @@@ 
 EntityValue[
  EntityClass["AdministrativeDivision", 
 "ContiguousUSStates"], 
  EntityProperty["AdministrativeDivision", "Polygon"]], 
 GeoStyling[Blue], bedrockPliocene}, 
 GeoCenter -> 
 Entity["City", {"NewOrleans", "Louisiana", 
 "UnitedStates"}], 
 GeoRange -> Quantity[1500, "Miles"], GeoBackground -> 
"ReliefMap"];
```

However, when one uses `Show` to combine them, the `GeoRange` is altered:

```
Show[paleocene, eocene, miocene, pliocene]
```

**Is there a way to constrict subsequent graphics plots to retain the same GeoRange values as the first plot in the combined plot?**

Comment: Can you include an explantation of how the georange is altered and what you expected instead?

Comment: `Legended[Show[paleocene, eocene, miocene, pliocene, GeoRange -> Quantity[1500, "Miles"]], SwatchLegend[{Red, Yellow, Green, Blue}, {"Paleocene", "Eocene", "Miocene", "Pliocene"}, LegendLabel -> "bedrock polygon"]]`

Comment: Apologies for not getting back to this sooner.  Bob Hanlon's suggestion worked giving me what I had expected.  Thank you.  Moving your comment to the answer section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Bob Hanlon's comment, this issue is resolved and nice legends added, which is a bonus. Any points go to him.

```
Legended[Show[paleocene, eocene, miocene, pliocene,
  GeoRange -> Quantity[1500, "Miles"]],
  SwatchLegend[{Red, Yellow, Green, Blue},
  {"Paleocene", "Eocene", "Miocene", "Pliocene"},
  LegendLabel -> "bedrock polygon"]]
```

– Bob Hanlon Jul 31 at 1:23

Comment: To my chagrin, it seems that data for other parts of the world besides the USA appear to be lacking, making this less useful than one might hope.  Mathematica-oriented geologists are needed to come to the rescue.